# Buying the right memory for 13" Macbook Pro Mid 2012

Tags: mac, memory, macbook, macbook-pro

I want to upgrade my 13" Macbook Pro Mid 2012 to 8 gb RAM (is has 4 gb now). I want to buy Crucial RAM and I selected my Macbook model on their website. The website then shows me all compatible hardware for my Macbook version. I get this product as compatible [on the Crucial website](http://eu.crucial.com/eur/en/macbook-pro-%2813-inch-and-15-inch%2C-mid-2012%29/CT3373647). However, their delivery service takes long to deliver. I want to order the exact same product from a Dutch webshop (as they deliver in 24 hours), but this is the product that's closest to the one on the Crucial website: [Crucial RAM in Dutch webshop](http://www.memoryshop.nl/product/309891/category-198084/crucial-apple-8-gb-sodimm-ddr3-1600-2-x-4-gb.html).

However, on the Crucial website, the RAM has hardware number `CT3373647`. On the Dutch webshop, the hardware number is `CT2C4G3S160BMCEU`. Are these the same products with different codes or something? I want to make sure I buy the right hardware version for my Macbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)

Official specs support up to 8 GB using two 4 GB 1600 MHz ram.

They are both the same. Apple Support Article [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp649?locale=en_US).

The crucial links are for 8 GB Kit ( 2 x 4 GB). I would recommend a single 8 GB over 2 x 4 GB, so later if you need to upgrade again, you can just install another 8 GB. Else, you would have to remove the 8 GB Kit and then go for the 16 GB Kit for the maximum.

You can refer memorystock.com for the specs too, though I highly doubt they have 24 hrs delivery as they are located at California.

Note: Users have tried with two 8 GB DDR3 1600 MHz SODIMM RAM for a successful upgrade of 16 GB.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! But in the 'About this Mac' section it says max memory capacity is 8 gb (and 2x4 installed).

Comment: Correct, Apple says 8 GB is the maximum then at that time. Later users have successfully upgraded to a total of 16 GB 1600 MHz memory. You can try if you would like to. And that is why most sites list 16 GB as the total possible upgrade for this variant